# How to select only those records that have at least one associated record?

Tags: cakephp, query-builder, cakephp-3.1

I have the following associations: `Orders` belongsTo `Sites`

I execute the following query:

```
$sites = $this->Sites->find('all')
->select(['id', 'name'])
->contain([
        'Users' => function ($q) {
                return $q->select(['id', 'owner_id', 'firstname', 'lastname']);
        },
        'Orders' => function ($q) {
                return $q->where(['status >' => 0]);
        },
        'Orders.Agplans'
])
->matching('Users', function ($q) use($owner_id)
{
    return $q->where([
        'Users.owner_id' => $owner_id
    ]);
})
->all();
```

But most of the sites have no orders so I get some kind of results:

```
(int) 100 => object(App\Model\Entity\Site) {
    'id' => (int) 7966,
    'name' => 'Site example',
    'orders' => [],
    'users' => [
        (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\User) {

    ...
```

Is it possible to specify in the query that I only want `sites` with not empty `orders`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since what you have there is a `hasMany` association, you'll have to take measures additionally to containing `Orders`.

### Use an inner join

You could use an `INNER` join, that would select only those rows where a matching order is present. For filtering purposes, this can easily be done using `Query::innerJoinWith()`, which is similar to `Query::matching()`, but it won't load any results.

```
$sites = $this->Sites
    ->find('all')
    ->select(['id', 'name'])

    // ...

    ->innerJoinWith('Orders', function ($q) {
        return $q->where(['Orders.status >' => 0]);
    })
    ->group(['Sites.id']) // may or may not be necessary
    ->all();
```

### Use matching like you already do

You are already using `Query::matching()` for `Users`, so I'd assume that you know what it does... filtering. Adding a further matching for `Orders` is an option too, it will however fetch additional data.

```
$sites = $this->Sites
    ->find('all')
    ->select(['id', 'name'])

    // ...

    ->matching('Orders', function ($q) {
        return $q->where(['Orders.status >' => 0]);
    })
    ->group(['Sites.id']) // may or may not be necessary
    ->all();
```

### Last but not least, use a counter cache

Using a properly indexed counter cache is probably the best performing option, as filtering would be done via a column in the same table.

You'd define it in your `Orders` model with the proper conditions, and then just use `where()` in your query, like

```
$this->addBehavior('CounterCache', [
    'Sites' => [
        'active_orders_count' => [
            'conditions' => ['Orders.status >' => 0]
        ]
    ]
]);
```

```
$sites = $this->Sites
    ->find('all')
    ->select(['id', 'name'])

    // ...

    ->where([
        'active_orders_count >' => 0
    ])
    ->all();
```

### See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Using innerJoinWith](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-innerjoinwith)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Filtering by Associated Data](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#filtering-by-associated-data)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Behaviors > Counter Cache](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/counter-cache.html)**

Comment: thanks ndm. matching is done on ``Users`` and not on ``Orders`` anyway I'm going to explore your solution.