# CakePhp3: Select registers count greater than in relationship Has Many

Tags: cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0, has-many, cakephp-3.x

I have one doubt how to solve this. I have two tables, properties and images with a relationship Has Many. One property can have 0,1 or more images related. I want to search properties that has more than 1 image related. I tried with:

```
$propertiesExclusive = $this->Properties->find('all')->contain( [ 'PropertyTags', 

        'ImagesAffiliates' => function($e){
                        $e->group([ 'ImagesAffiliates.id HAVING (COUNT(ImagesAffiliates.id) > 1 )' ]);

                return $e;

        }])

    ->order(['id' => 'DESC'])->where(['exclusive' => 1])->where($defaultWhere)->limit(7)->all();
```

The idea is that if a property doesnt have images or only has one, we don't get it.

I tried in several forms but no way.

Comment: Can you try to replace the "contain" function by "matching"? https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#filtering-by-associated-data-via-matching-and-joins

Comment: **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34528298/how-to-select-only-those-records-that-have-at-least-one-associated-record**

Comment: I put:->matching([
    
    'ImagesAffiliates' => function ($q) {

           return $q->select(
               [
                   'id',
                   'property_id',
                   'count' => $q->func()->count('*')
              ])
              ->group(['property_id']);

                       
          
   }])

   -> And I have the following error on cakephp3<b>Warning</b> (2)</a>: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given [<b>CORE/src/ORM/EagerLoader.php</b>, line <b>228</b>]

Comment: @ndm the example is itneresting when you want to get deep assotiation and the relation has a condition, but in our case we need the count of that condition and then get a condition again.  I think is not valid for me.

Comment: You don't have to use conditions, they are completely optional. From the description in your question, all you need is an inner join on `ImagesAffiliates` (and grouping by `Properties` I suppose). If you have any further requirments other than the one described/shown currently, then please update your question to reflect that.

Comment: $propertiesNew = $this->Properties->find('all')->select([ 'total_images' => $propertiesNew->func()->count('ImagesAffiliates.id')])
       ->leftJoinWith('ImagesAffiliates')
       ->group(['ImagesAffiliates.property_id'])
       ->enableAutoFields(true)->all(); If i do this, I get in a field the total images of the property but If i try to do a where cake says that the column total_images doesnt exist

Comment: I need all properties that have more than 2 images in one query.

Comment: I see, I should've scrolled rightwards, maybe I would have read the question correctly then... That won't work using `SELECT` (only), in that case you'd need to add your `HAVING` condition [**via the `Query::having()` method**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#aggregates-group-and-having).

Comment: @ndm Thanks, you got it. I had to mix both things. This is the solution: $this->Properties->find('all')->contain('PropertyTags')->contain('ImagesAffiliates')->select([ 'total_images' => $propertiesNew->func()->count('ImagesAffiliates.id'), 'ImagesAffiliates.id' ])
       ->leftJoinWith('ImagesAffiliates')
       ->group(['ImagesAffiliates.property_id'])
       ->enableAutoFields(true)->order(['listing_entry_date' => 'DESC'])->where($defaultWhere)->where(['Properties.id NOT IN' => $exclusiveIds ])->having(['total_images >' => 4])->limit(7)->all();  *  it works. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @adm. You got it. I had to mix the select with having for refering to the "alias" total_images field.

```
 $this->Properties->find('all')->contain('ImagesAffiliates')->select([ 'total_images' => $propertiesNew->func()->count('ImagesAffiliates.id'), 'ImagesAffiliates.id' ])
                ->leftJoinWith('ImagesAffiliates')
                ->group(['ImagesAffiliates.property_id'])
                ->enableAutoFields(true)->having(['total_images >' => 2])->limit(7)->all();
```